# function to initialize variables in C

Tags: c

I should use a function to assign initial values to variables, but don't understand why the init function in my code doesn't initialize the a, b, c, it gives some garbage numbers. Also I should use a rotate function using a static declaration of variables a, b, c , but since its static it doesn't swap variables. How I do that?

```
 void init(int num1, int num2, int num3);

 int main(void){

 int a, b, c;



 init(a, b, c); 


 printf("a=%d, b=%d,  c=%d\n", a, b, c);


rotate();

 return 0;
 }

 void init(int num1, int num2, int num3){

 printf("Enter value for num1: ");
 scanf("%d",&num1);
 printf("Enter values for num2: ");
 scanf("%d",&num2);
 printf("Enter values for num3: ");
 scanf("%d",&num3);
 }


void rotate(void){
static int a,b,c;
int temp;
temp=a;
a=b;
b=c;
c=temp;}
```

Comment: For c you'll need to pass the variables addresses (pointers) to initialize them from within a function.

Comment: but I have to use void init(int num1, int num2, int num3), not void init(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3), in that case how I can use pointers

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. It's being passed by value; it's *not* the same `numN` as you're passing.

Comment: The only way I see this being the case would be to have `a, b and c` as global variables, and the parametres of the call would be the initialising value. But it's not a good way of working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is attempting to pass by ***value***.
However, in C, passing a non-array variable by ***address*** is the *only* way to allow a function to change it.

Your use of function arguments can be corrected like this...
Change function to:

```
void init(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3){

 printf("Enter value for num1: ");
 scanf("%d",num1);//because argument is already a 
                  //pointer, you do not need to de-reference (&)
 printf("Enter values for num2: ");
 scanf("%d",num2);
 printf("Enter values for num3: ");
 scanf("%d",num3);
 }
```

And, Change call:

```
 init(a, b, c);
```

to:

```
 init(&a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: thank you, then how about rotate function declaring static var, I tried this, but it doesn't work, I shouldn't take arguments for rotate.  
void rotate(){
static int a, b, c;
int  *temp, *p, *q, *r;
p=&a;
q=&b;
r=&c;
temp=p;
p=q;
q=r;
r=temp;
}

Comment: Your function rotate is prototyped as void void, meaning it is not passed any variables, and it returns nothing.  Also, the variables `a, b, c` have a lifespan only in that function.  They are completely different then the `a, b, c` in the main function.  ***To fix:*** Do the same for that function as I described doing for the init() function, i.e. prototype it with `int *,...`, then pass `&a,...`. (and remove `int a;, and others` inside the rotate function, because they will be passed as pointer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function declaration and definition to

```
void init(int *num1, int *num2, int *num3)
```

And call the function using

```
init(&a, &b, &c);
```

Also remove the `&` in all the `scanf` in that function as you are already passing adresses of the variables to the function.